# Oidc-client-js trigger login when app start.What is the correct way?

Tags: oidc-client-js

i am using identity server 4 and oidc-client-js for auth, with angular frame work. I faced it this issue,

I am trying to trigger login redirect when application start. First i tried this code;

```
this.authService.userManager.getUser().then((user) => {
    if (!(user)) {
      this.authService.userManager.signinRedirect();
    }
});
```

and user always returning null. Then i tried the same code with timeout, like this;

```
this.authService.userManager.getUser().then((user) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    if (!(user)) {
      this.authService.userManager.signinRedirect();
    }
  }, 2000);
});
```

after that, everything works good. But i'm not comfortable about using timeout. I tried using subject in callback component signinRedirectCallback, i tried userLoaded event but i can't succeeded. And finally i wrote this code;

In app component ngOnInit;

```
if (!this.authService.currentUser) {
      this.authService.userManager.signinRedirectCallback().then((user) => {
        //  this.authService.userLoadedSub.next(user);
        this.authService.currentUser = user;
        console.log("01");
        //navigate related route

        this.initData();
      }).catch((err) => {
        console.log("signinRedirectCallback Error", err);
        this.authService.userManager.signinRedirect();
      });
    }
```

Is this a good way to what i need? Is there any other way?

Many thanks for yor helps.